# Getting errors when trying to create an SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I already have the database created, and when I go to create a table within it, It's giving me an error of

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Â INT unsigned PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Â Â Â  `UserID`Â  INT NOT NULL, Â ' at line 2

```
CREATE TABLE `lists` 
( `ListID`     INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserID`     INT NOT NULL,
  `ListURL`      VARCHAR(150)
)
```

I've tried simple things, and I've added those backticks because I've seen that as a solution to a lot of issues on here, but it's still giving me back the same error. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Get rid of all the unnecessary whitespace and try it again.

Comment: Can you run DML statements?  Does *anything* run correctly with the interface you're using?

Comment: works for me, get rid of white space or if you are using wamp try creating this table using sql console

Comment: Looks like a problem with the whitespace including characters which MySQL is not seeing as whitespace. Try removing all the whitespace except for a single space.

Answer (score 0):

What text editor did you use to save this command? Did you save it with Word or another similar editor, which may be adding non-ASCII characters to the file?

Comment: I'm typing it directly into phpMyAdmin. I'll check to make sure that there's nothing but spaces between everything.